# Is there a way you can set min and max previous scores as markers on a slider?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently my slider has a bind able value of the users last recorded score, is there any way i can set it so it can show their min and max score recorded via a marker on the slider.

[image: immage]
Something like this in the picture, is this doable using xamarin forms ?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to colorize the separate parts of the slider with different colors, you should look into the [XFGloss](https://github.com/tbaggett/xfgloss) library which provides attached bindable properties for use with the Slider control.

[image]

You can use it the following way:

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="25" 
        xfg:SliderGloss.MinTrackTintColor="Green" 
        xfg:SliderGloss.MaxTrackTintColor="Red" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having to use external libraries like xfg, try with the following built-in properties. This will do the trick.

```
Slider.Minimum
Slider.MinimumTrackColor
Slider.Maximum
Slider.MaximumTrackColor
```

You then can use a couple of labels to indicate your min-max values over the slider.